# How to show this attribute for regular integrals?

Tags: analysis

I need to show this attribute for any $ x \in \mathbb{R}$
for regular integrals:

$$\int_0^x f(t)(x-t) \, dt = \int_0^x \left( \int_0^u f(t) \,dt \right) \,du$$

Well,my plan was to solve each of the sites..and show that they are equal.But that doesnt work. Have you any ideas?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Define $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$ as follows.
$$F_1(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt \space \text{ and }F_2(x)=\int_0^xF_1(t)dt$$
Now we can write RHS as $$\int_{0}^{x} F_1(u) - F_1(0)du = F_2(x)-F_2(0) -xF_1(x)$$
Now we can use Product rule to rewrite the LHS as follows
$$x\int_0^x f(t)dt -\int_0^xtf(t)dt=\bigg(x(F_1(x)-F_1(0))\bigg) -\bigg(tF_1(t)\bigg|_0^x -\int_0^xF_1(t)dt\bigg)$$
$$=F_2(x)-F_2(0)-xF_1(x)$$
Same as we got on the RHS, and therefore we are done.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^x \left( \int_0^u f(t) \,dt \right) \,du \\[10pt]
= {} & \iint\limits_{\{ (t,u)\,:\, 0 \,\le\,t\,\le\,u\,\le\,x \}} f(t)\, d(t,u) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^x \left( \int_t^x f(t) \,du \right) dt \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^x\left( f(t) \int_t^x 1\,du \right) dt & & \left(\begin{array}{c} \text{This can be done because $f(t)$ does} \\ \text{not change as $u$ goes from $t$ to $x$.} \end{array}\right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^x f(t) (x-t) \, dt.
\end{align}